# Jquery Select2 With plain ASP.net (No MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-select2

I am Trying to use select2 with `<select></select>` control and i am just not able to get it right. i am posting my script below.

My control.

`<select id="select2" runat="server" multiple="true" width="170px"></select>`

The scripts i am importing.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/select2.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Scripts/select2.min.css" />`

`$("#select.<%=select2.ClientID%>").select2();`

and i am populating my  control from code behind on page load.

the error i get is `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
and the output i get is.
[image]

what i want is a drop down list where users can select multiple values from the populated values.
by the way i am using the latest version of select2.js

Comment: change ``$("#select.<%=select2.ClientID%>").select2();`` to ``$("#"+<%=select2.ClientID%>).select2();`` and put it in document.ready

Comment: If your `select2.min.js` contains jQuery, you need to place that file after `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` when you are importing them otherwise that will throw undefined errors.

Comment: Thanks for Replying guys but non of them worked still having problems

Answer (score 0):

I test it and it works for me

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select id="select2" runat="server" multiple="true" width="170px">
    <option value="11111">11111</option>
    <option value="22222">22222</option>
    <option value="33333">33333</option>
    <option value="44444">44444</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#<%=select2.ClientID%>" ).select2();
</script>
```

Comment: i will try it out as i found a work around it but i am gonna try select2 once again . thanks